# What's the difference between each sentence and are they both correct?

Tags: grammaticality, differences, clauses

- I had thought it *would be* different before I took the test.
- I had thought it *would have been* different before I took the test.

Comment: I think they're essentially the same. The difference in nuance seems to be the implied location of the assumed present in relation to when you though it would be different.

Answer (score 1):

The past perfect is generally used when you describe something that happened before another thing.

The sentence seems to imply that you thought things would be one way, and then you took the test and realized that things were actually not that way.

If this is what the sentence means, you should say one of

> I had thought it would be different before I took the test,
> I thought it would be different before I took the test.

In the first sentence above, you use *had thought* because you thought that before you took the test.

In the second sentence above, you can replace the past perfect with the simple past because the order of events is clear, and when this is true, you can generally use the simple past instead of the past perfect.

In your second sentence

> I had thought it would have been different before I took the test,

you have two past perfect tenses, and these both need to describe the time before you took the test (but probably not the time after). I don't quite see how this is possible.